# MySQL insists on trying to use InnoDB even when told not to, please help

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.5, myisam

We're trying out MySQL 5.5, and have installed it on one of our slave servers as a test run. Our main server is 5.0, and we have zero optimization here for InnoDB, so I want everything to just be MyISAM for now. I've disabled InnoDB everywhere I can think, but the replication is throwing errors like:

`Error 'Unknown storage engine 'InnoDB'' on query. Default database: ''. Query: 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ... SELECT ...`

The query never specifies the engine is InnoDB. `default-storage-engine` is set toMyISAM. `innodb` is set to OFF. Why is it trying to create this termporary table as InnoDB? This is 5.5, not 5.6, so we don't have the `default-tmp-storage-engine` variable yet. Please help, this is driving me insane.

Comment: Rolando provided the answer to your question as asked, but I question your reasons for using MyISAM.  There are virtually no good reasons to use MyISAM anymore and the ease of which MyISAM tables become corrupted is a very good reason not to use it.

Comment: Simply put, it's more important to get the replication caught up using MyISAM than taking the time to optimize InnoDB to the level that we have MyISAM optimized. I fully intend to use InnoDB, but not at this very moment. InnoDB tables were taking days to do what MyISAM can do in hours, so yes, there IS a good reason to use MyISAM.

Comment: Son of a gumble, I have a theory. I can't see the entire query, it's being cut off, but my guess is, it's trying to create this temporary table based on one of the tables that was created as InnoDB before I noticed the problem, and thus, by doing "CREATE ... SELECT", it's trying to create the temporary table in the image of the InnoDB table. That's the best I have to go on at the moment...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To disable InnoDB, add this to /etc/my.cnf on the MySQL 5.5. slave:

```
[mysqld]
skip-innodb
```

and run this on the Slave:

```
service mysql restart
```

According to MySQL Documentation on [**CREATE TABLE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html) :

> You can create one table from another by adding a SELECT statement at the end of the CREATE TABLE statement:
>
> CREATE TABLE new_tbl SELECT * FROM orig_tbl;
>   For more information, see Section 13.1.17.1, “CREATE TABLE ... SELECT Syntax”.
>
> Use LIKE to create an empty table based on the definition of another table, including any column attributes and indexes defined in the original table:
>
> CREATE TABLE new_tbl LIKE orig_tbl;
>
> The copy is created using the same version of the table storage format as the original table. The SELECT privilege is required on the original table.

You must specify the ENGINE upon creation

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ... ENGINE=MyISAM SELECT ...
```

to get around this problem

Comment: Doesn't work. Still getting the error "Unknown storage engine 'InnoDB'", despite the `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` instruction not specifying InnoDB. `skip-innodb` is there, `default-storage-engine = MyISAM` is there. Any ideas why it's trying to create this table as InnoDB?

Answer (score -1):

[InnoDB is the default storage engine in MySQL 5.5.5.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/storage-engine-setting.html) You need to specify otherwise in the [my.cnf](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_default-storage-engine) by using:

```
default-storage-engine = MYISAM
```

-- *redacted inaccurate content* --

Comment: I said in my post I already have that in the config. The default storage engine is set to MyISAM, and InnoDB is disabled. Yet when trying to create this temporary table, it insists on trying InnoDB, yet the query to create the table does not specify it should use the InnoDB Engine.

Comment: Okay, did a little more digging and updated answer. It appears you cannot set the storage type of temporary tables until MySQL 5.6.3.

Comment: According to the documentation, `default-storage-engine` applies to both regular and temporary tables in < 5.5.

Comment: Andrew, please supply a link to the documentation that states "default-storage-engine applies to both regular and temporary tables" so we can benefit from the knowledge.

Comment: I was mistaken, it's not <5.5, it's <5.6.3. From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/storage-engine-setting.html "Before MySQL 5.6.3, default_storage_engine sets the engine for both permanent and TEMPORARY tables."

Comment: I would submit this as a bug to MySQL. I think there are possibly two different animals: 1.) Internal TEMP tables and 2.) User generated TEMP tables. If you do an EXPLAIN on your query, does it say "USING TEMPORARY" in the EXTRA column?

Comment: I already figured out the problem, as indicated above in the 'son of a gumble' comment.